# COBOL Sorting Transaction File

Tags: sorting, cobol

How to sort a tran file which has this kind of record..

```
AT key taname username
AP key prname prshortname
DT key taname username
CT key taname username
CP key prname prshortname
DP key prname prshortname
```

WHat i need to do is sort this tran file in Delete, Add, Change sequence.. 
is there any way ? Thanks in advance..

```
AT = add task;
AP = add proj;
DT = delete task;
DP = delete proj;
CT = change task;
CP = change proj;
```

Comment: Delete, Add, Change is an unusual sequence. Are you sure of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could read the file into a table, adding a sort sequence number based on the transaction type.  The sort sequence number would be looked up from a table.  Then sort the table on the sort sequence and the key in the record.  For example, your code could include (syntax is not perfect, but should point you in the right direction):

```
01  TRANSACTION-TYPES.
```

* ORDERED AS DELETE ADD CHANGE

```
    05  FILLER                  PIC X(4) VALUE 'DT01'.
    05  FILLER                  PIC X(4) VALUE 'DP02'.
    05  FILLER                  PIC X(4) VALUE 'AT03'.
    05  FILLER                  PIC X(4) VALUE 'AP04'.
    05  FILLER                  PIC X(4) VALUE 'CT05'.
    05  FILLER                  PIC X(4) VALUE 'CP06'.

01  TRANS-TYPE-TABLE REDEFINES TRANSACTION-TYPES.

    05  TRANS-TYPE OCCURS 6 TIMES INDEXED BY TRANS-INDEX.
        10  TRANS-CODE          PIC XX.
        10  TRANS-SORT          PIC 99.

01  TRANSACTION-TABLE.

    05  TRANS-RECORD OCCURS 1 to 1000 TIMES DEPENDING ON TRANS-COUNT
        INDEXED BY TABLE-INDEX.
        10  TRANS-TABLE-SORT        PIC 99.
        10  TRANS-TABLE-DETAIL      PIC X(132).
...

ADD-RECORD-TO-TABLE.

    MOVE IN-RECORD TO TRANS-TABLE-DETAIL (TABLE-INDEX)
    SET TRANS-INDEX TO 1
    SEARCH TRANS-TYPE
        AT END MOVE HIGH-VALUE TO TRANS-TABLE-SORT (TABLE-INDEX)
        WHEN IN-RECORD-TRANS-CODE = TRANS-CODE (TRANS-INDEX)
            MOVE TRANS-SORT (TRANS-INDEX) TO TRANS-TABLE-SORT (TABLE-INDEX)
    .

...

SORT TRANS-RECORD

    ON ASCENDING KEY TRANS-TABLE-SORT
    ON ASCENDING KEY TRANS-TABLE-DETAIL.
```

Comment: i was able to grasp the idea.. i'll try this right away .. thanks!

Comment: Thanks, Bill.  Order fixed to delete, add, and change (assuming task before project (not specified)).

Comment: @ValdisGrinbergs, OK I've deleted my comment, and will delete this one when you delete your comment to me. Keeps things tidier.

Answer (score 1):

```
EVALUATE TRUE
    WHEN first-char-shows-add
        MOVE outsort-adds to sort-transaction-category
    WHEN first-char-shows-change
        MOVE outsort-change to sort-transaction-category
    WHEN first-char-shows-delete
        MOVE outsort-deletes to sort-transaction-category
    WHEN OTHER
        deal with to your local standards
END-EVALUATE
```

The WHENs have appropriately-named 88s, and the values MOVEd are data-names with VALUE statements. Say, "3" "5" "7" or anything you like to get you the order.

You put your input record into your record to sort first, then put the outsort field in, then sort the records. Can be done in input/output procedures.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to use SORT with INPUT PROCEDURE and OUTPUT PROCEDURE clauses.

The **example below is only for hints**, but should lead to an acceptable solution.  Within the procedures you are in near complete control of when and how to RELEASE input records to the sort file, and how you manage RETURN records through the output procedure.

For fun and typing, you can chain them as filters, or convert the few types to an enum and stuff the value in a primary key for a single INPUT PROCEDURE IS pass. You could skip the OUTPUT PROCEDURE IS phrase and mix in a GIVING, or play nice and use the the OUTPUT PROCEDURE to convert the enums back to human readable tags.

```
OCOBOL >>SOURCE FORMAT IS FIXED
      ******************************************************************
      * Date:      02-Sep-2008
      * Purpose:   An OpenCOBOL SORT verb example
      * Tectonics: cobc -x sorting.cob
      *     ./sorting <input >output
      *   or simply 
      *     ./sorting
      *   for keyboard and screen demos 
      ******************************************************************
       identification division.
       program-id. sorting.

       environment division.
       configuration section.
      * This sets up a sort order lower then upper except for A and a
       special-names.
           alphabet mixed is " AabBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTu
      -"UvVwWxXyYzZ0123456789".

       input-output section.
       file-control.
           select sort-in
               assign keyboard
               organization is line sequential.
           select sort-out
               assign display
               organization is line sequential.
           select sort-work
               assign "sortwork".

       data division.
       file section.
       fd sort-in.
          01 in-rec        pic x(255).
       fd sort-out.
          01 out-rec       pic x(255).
       sd sort-work.
          01 work-rec      pic x(255).

       working-storage section.
       01 loop-flag        pic x value low-value.

       procedure division.
       sort sort-work
           on descending key work-rec
           collating sequence is mixed
           input procedure is sort-transform
           output procedure is output-uppercase.

       display sort-return end-display.
       goback.

      ******************************************************************
       sort-transform.
       move low-value to loop-flag
       open input sort-in
       read sort-in
           at end move high-value to loop-flag
       end-read
       perform
           until loop-flag = high-value
               move FUNCTION LOWER-CASE(in-rec) to work-rec
               release work-rec
               read sort-in
                   at end move high-value to loop-flag
               end-read
       end-perform
       close sort-in
       .

      ******************************************************************
       output-uppercase.
       move low-value to loop-flag
       open output sort-out
       return sort-work
           at end move high-value to loop-flag
       end-return
       perform
           until loop-flag = high-value
               move FUNCTION UPPER-CASE(work-rec) to out-rec
               write out-rec end-write
               return sort-work
                   at end move high-value to loop-flag
               end-return
       end-perform
       close sort-out
       .

       exit program.
       end program sorting.
```

See http://opencobol.add1tocobol.com/#sort for more details.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the number of sort buckets that you have to deal with is a small fixed number (6). You could use a utility such 
as SYNCSORT to split the transaction file into six subfiles 
based on the: DT, DP, AT, AP, CT, CP tag values on each record. Next
sort the individual files based on whatever other criteria are appropriate. Next concatenate the six sorted subfiles in the required order.